# how can my RFID reader reading a RFID tag only once?

Tags: c#, sdk, rfid

I have impinj speedway reader and I'm using impinj Ocatne SDK for .net and visual studio 2013 (c#) in order to test and deploy the device. As a first exercise, i executed the example "readtags (described below) of Ocatne SDK, so the reader reads the tags many times until I give up running. However, I would like to know how the reader can read tags only once
Thanks

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            // Connect to the reader.
            // Change the ReaderHostname constant in SolutionConstants.cs 
            // to the IP address or hostname of your reader.
            reader.Connect(SolutionConstants.ReaderHostname);

            // Get the default settings
            // We'll use these as a starting point
            // and then modify the settings we're 
            // interested in.
            Settings settings = reader.QueryDefaultSettings();

            // Tell the reader to include the antenna number
            // in all tag reports. Other fields can be added
            // to the reports in the same way by setting the 
            // appropriate Report.IncludeXXXXXXX property.
            settings.Report.IncludeAntennaPortNumber = true;

            // The reader can be set into various modes in which reader
            // dynamics are optimized for specific regions and environments.
            // The following mode, AutoSetDenseReader, monitors RF noise and interference and then automatically
            // and continuously optimizes the reader’s configuration
            settings.ReaderMode = ReaderMode.AutoSetDenseReader;
            settings.SearchMode = SearchMode.DualTarget;
            settings.Session = 2;

            // Enable antenna #1. Disable all others.
            settings.Antennas.DisableAll();
            settings.Antennas.GetAntenna(1).IsEnabled = true;

            // Set the Transmit Power and 
            // Receive Sensitivity to the maximum.
            settings.Antennas.GetAntenna(1).MaxTxPower = true;
            settings.Antennas.GetAntenna(1).MaxRxSensitivity = true;
            // You can also set them to specific values like this...
            //settings.Antennas.GetAntenna(1).TxPowerInDbm = 20;
            //settings.Antennas.GetAntenna(1).RxSensitivityInDbm = -70;

            // Apply the newly modified settings.
            reader.ApplySettings(settings);

            // Assign the TagsReported event handler.
            // This specifies which method to call
            // when tags reports are available.
            reader.TagsReported += OnTagsReported;

            // Start reading.
            reader.Start();
// Wait for the user to press enter.
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();


            // Stop reading.
            reader.Stop();

            // Disconnect from the reader.
            reader.Disconnect();
        }
        catch (OctaneSdkException e)
        {
            // Handle Octane SDK errors.
            Console.WriteLine("Octane SDK exception: {0}", e.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Handle other .NET errors.
            Console.WriteLine("Exception : {0}", e.Message);
        }
    }

    static void OnTagsReported(ImpinjReader sender, TagReport report)
    {
        // This event handler is called asynchronously 
        // when tag reports are available.
        // Loop through each tag in the report 
        // and print the data.

        foreach (Tag tag in report)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("voici l'antenne : {0}, EPC : {1} ", tag.AntennaPortNumber, tag.Epc);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Without knowing much about your RFID reader, I'm not sure it's job is to only read things once and then stop. I think it's your job in code to handle that. If you want to ignore multiple reads, then get a list of what you've read and then if you have read it again discard the second read.

Comment: @Prescott My RFID reader is Impinj Speedway R420. For example if i like read tags for 5 seconds every 10 seconds I can write this code:                             settings.AutoStart.Mode = AutoStartMode.Periodic;
                settings.AutoStart.PeriodInMs = 10000;
                settings.AutoStop.Mode = AutoStopMode.Duration;
                settings.AutoStop.DurationInMs = 30;                                      I like to know if there is functions that allow me to read a tag only once

Answer (score 0):

You can write your program to filter and report tag reads in any number of ways. Impinj provides [sample code](https://docs.impinj.com/display/PD/Speedway+Connect+Sample+Code) to make it easier for you to get started in terms of data output.

Also, download the latest version of the [Octane SDK](https://support.impinj.com/hc/en-us/articles/202755268-Octane-SDK), open the folder, navigate to "examples", then navigate to (and open) "ReadTagsFiltered" for sample code related to filtering tag reads.

Answer (score 0):

If you set Search Mode to 'Single Target' and use Session 2, the reader will (physically) only read a tag once when it enters the field, and will read it again when it has been out of the field for more than a few seconds. This will enhance the read performance as well (as the reader as more time to read other tags).

You can of course also filter in software, and track which EPCs has already been read.

For more background on Session in RFID, please read here: https://github.com/rainrfid/overview/wiki/2.-The-protocol

Comment: since I am a beginner in RFID I want to know how can i track with EPCs has already been read. I suppose that i should add a condition in the code below:  foreach (Tag tag in report)
            {  
                Console.WriteLine("voici l'antenne : {0}, EPC : {1} ", tag.AntennaPortNumber, tag.Epc);  
                
            }

Comment: You can keep a List with all the tags that have been read before, and check whether a tag exists in that list before writing it to the console.

Answer (score 0):

When you use Session 2 and Single Target, the tag will respond only once, until it has been out of the field for more than a certain amount of time.